# Select items from database that don't have a combination of values

Tags: mysql

In my table I have two columns: finished and closed. I want a select that shows all items that don't have BOTH values at 1. This is what I'm trying but It will not show items that have one of them at 1 and the other at 0:

```
 select * from `operations` where (`finished` != 1 and `closed` != 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 select * from `operations` where (`finished` != 1 or `closed` != 1)
```

should do the trick, or alternatively

```
 select * from `operations` where !(`finished` = 1 and `closed` = 1)
```

You can use your English sentence to decode. What I mean is, "have both values at 1" is equivalent to `finished=1 and closed=1`, then "do not have both..." is like the `not` of that, i.e. `!(finished=1 and closed=1)`.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I will mark as resolved in 9 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

Items that don't have *both* values at `1` will have one *or* the other as non-`1`.

Hence you need:

```
select * from `operations`
where `finished` != 1 or `closed` != 1
```

Simplifying the values as either `1` or `0` will see you get:

```
finished  closed  result
--------  ------  ------
       0       0    T
       0       1    T
       0       0    T
       1       1    F
```

---

That's one reading of your question. The other (though unlikely) is that you want to know which rows have *one* of the values at `1` but not the other. You can get that with:

```
select * from `operations`
where (`finished` != 1 or `closed` != 1) and `finished` != `closed`
```

The result table for that would be:

```
finished  closed  result
--------  ------  ------
       0       0    F
       0       1    T
       1       0    T
       1       1    F
```

---

Your original query used `and` where it should have used `or` (assuming you want the first result above). That only selected rows where *both* values were non-`1`:

```
finished  closed  result
--------  ------  ------
       0       0    T
       0       1    F
       1       0    F
       1       1    F
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the SQL `OR` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM `operations` WHERE `finished` != 1 OR `closed` != 1
```